# Snoowrap - How to get all posts from a subreddit before a certain date?

Tags: javascript, api, reddit

I'm trying to **scrape** subreddits. It would be helpful if I can search in the past.

Can I pass a **before** date parameter in

```
 r.getSubreddit('snoowrap').getNew().then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying API call is [GET (/r/subreddit)/new](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_new), so yes, it looks like you can pass a `before` parameter, but it's a pagination token ("get items before this item"), not a date.